# Django: How can I check the last activity time of user if user didn't log out?

Tags: python, django, middleware

django's User model has a `last_login` field, which is great if all the users were to log out each time they leave the site, but what if they don't?

How can I track when a user who never logged out and his activity on the site?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to have the `last_activity` field in the user profile (or custom user model). This field will be updated on every request. To achieve this you need to have custom middleware:

profiles/middleware.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone

from myproject.profiles.models import Profile


class UpdateLastActivityMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user'), 'The UpdateLastActivityMiddleware requires authentication middleware to be installed.'
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            Profile.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id) \
                           .update(last_activity=timezone.now())
```

Add this middleware in your setting file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # other middlewares
    'myproject.profiles.middleware.UpdateLastActivityMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: It seems like this would result in a very large number of writes the database, potentially impacting performance. For something more efficient, consider writing the last activity into a cache and then periodically into the database. I believe that's what https://bitbucket.org/ferranp/django-last-seen probably does.

Comment: Although this answers the question, this broke my Django installation when the amount of users increased. It took some hours to figure out, so I hope this post saves someone some hours!

Answer (score 3):

i think in 2022 this will satisfy what you need also i did this and worked for me but the answer didnt.

put **LastActivityTraceMiddleware** after **AuthenticationMiddleware** in settings.py.

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from .... import MemberEntity


class LastActivityTraceMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        member: MemberEntity = request.user
        if member.is_authenticated:
            member.last_login = now()
            member.save()
        return response
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old ... and surely it has already been solved ...
but here is my contribution ...
In new versions of django you can use:

#### "Session Time" -> Used in configuration file. "settings.py"

If the user closes the browser, the session ends and must be logged in again ...

```py
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

If the user does not close the browser, you can set a time limit for the session ...

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60
```

For "SESSION_COOKIE_AGE" if I remember correctly it's defined in seconds.
You can see more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age)...
Recommended reading is also django's own [documentation about sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/)...