# Is it possible to check the user whether is on-line or off-line in Django project?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to check the user whether is on-line or off-line in Django project?

There is a requirement of check the users whether is on-line.

In my Django project, I have a after-sale group, in it there are several staff admin users.

I want to list their information, I also want to check whether they are login.

How to check it? I use `django-rest-auth`, there is a token to verify the users, I am not sure whether this helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200216/django-detect-if-user-is-online-offline

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663777/how-to-check-whether-a-user-is-online-in-django-template

Comment: For checking login you can try decorators like login required or some user authenticated , For to find online Using Caching you can do like mentioned [here](http://www.djangocurrent.com/2011/07/django-using-cashing-to-track-online.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - detect if user is online / offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200216/django-detect-if-user-is-online-offline)