# How to check user online and offline status

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to check and display user online status with django and django rest framework.

I have tried this article: [Django - detect if user is online / offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200216/django-detect-if-user-is-online-offline)
But did not work  on APIview only works on views with render and Httpresponse.

**Updated**

Here is the code for the middleware class

```
import datetime
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class ActiveUserMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        current_user = request.user
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        cache.set('seen_%s' % (current_user.username), now, settings.USER_LASTSEEN_TIMEOUT)
```

The APIView
    class ProfilePersonal(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

```
serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

def get(self):
    try:
        queryset = Account.objects.get()
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(data={'non_field_errors': 'Request could not be validated.'},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    serializer_data = self.serializer_class(queryset)

    return Response(
        data=serializer_data,
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK
    )
```

Comment: Can you share your current attempt? What is not working with it?

Comment: I did what is currently on the link I shared. On an APIView it does not work but on a normal view that returns a render function it works fine.

Comment: What exactly does it return in the APIView?

Comment: It displays False, that means the user is offline even if the user is currently authenticated