# Check User online Django 1.10

Tags: django, django-sessions, django-cache, django-caching

Hi trying to do like in example:

[How to check whether a user is online in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663777/how-to-check-whether-a-user-is-online-in-django-template)

but when adding 
`'userprofile.middleware.ActiveUserMiddleware',` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` 
recieving next error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fcf6e0b8668>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pavlo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pavlo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 40, in inner_run
    http_consumer=self.get_consumer(*args, **options),
  File "/home/pavlo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 136, in get_consumer
    return StaticFilesConsumer()
  File "/home/pavlo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.handler = self.handler_class()
  File "/home/pavlo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 18, in __init__
    super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__init__()
  File "/home/pavlo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 179, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/pavlo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Thx for help.

May be someone advise how to make check for online/offline users in Django 1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middlewares have changed in Django 1.10, see [this guide how to upgrade them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware)