# How to filter out queryset based on model method?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this query et:

```
plist = UserProfile.objects.filter(q).order_by('-created_at')
```

The model is:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    #some more fields


    def last_seen(self):
        return cache.get('seen_%s' % self.user.username)


    def online(self):
        if self.last_seen():
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            if now > self.last_seen() + datetime.timedelta(
                         seconds=settings.USER_ONLINE_TIMEOUT):
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

What I want to achieve is to filter out further `plist` to contain only online users.

I tried different tricks, like:

```
for p in plist:
    if p.online:
        print 'profile onlnine \n', p.id
        online_plist.append(p)
plist = online_plist
```

But it does not work. So appreciate your hints.

UPDATE: [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162699/4151875) how the online users cache is set:

```
class ActiveUserMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        current_user = request.user
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            cache.set('seen_%s' % (current_user.username), now, 
                           settings.USER_LASTSEEN_TIMEOUT)
```

Comment: You need to actually call the `online()` method in your if statement.

Comment: @DanielRoseman not sure how to do that. When I use `if  p.online()` instead, I get `User matching query does not exist.`. Will you please elaborate your answer with code sample?

Comment: That *is* what you do. That error is presumably caused by something in your `last_seen()` method, which you haven't shown.

Comment: sorry I added `last_seen()` method. The whole online code is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162699/4151875

Comment: @DanielRoseman please help!

Comment: I'm not sure what to you need help with. The error message tells you what is wrong: (at least) one particular UserProfile does not have an associated User.

Comment: Actually I can not get results even for `if not p.online(): ` while there are many offline users. The error track goes down to `return cache.get('seen_%s' % self.user.username) `

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of that comment.

Comment: Forget that. It turned out that there were some orphaned profiles so `user.username` did not satisfy. I put the `online` method in try..catch block and problem gone.  You are a great tutor DavidRoseman. Could not believe you help people on sundays too. Many thanks!