# Django: Online Users

Tags: django

I am following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162699/11801044) to show whether a user is online or not.
But when I try to add:

```
 'userprofile.middleware.ActiveUserMiddleware',
```

to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, I get a `502` error.

`{{ profile.online }}` returns `false`.

---

Thank you for any help.

---

**UPDATE**

It seems to work now without the middleware.

```
 {% if object.profile.is_online %}
 Online
 {% else %}
 Offline 
 {% endif %}
```

---

I have a list of users called "recommended".

```
{% recommended request user %}
```

Can I check within the template if these users are online?

{% recommended request user.is_online %}

does not work.

Thank you for any help / resource on this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Django-online-users works perfectly fine.