# Python websockets keepalive ping timeout; no close frame received

Tags: python, django, websocket

I have 20-50 users from whom I want real-time information about whether they are connected to the Internet or have a weak Internet

I wrote a Python script that checks the connection and sends the information to the web server in Django django-channels
script run in the Windows scheduler from 9 am to 6 pm

### **Script**

```
    async def main():
        username = get_username()
        url = "{}{}/".format(LOG_SERVER, username)
        async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
            # send info to server
            while True:
                try:
                    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, 
                                              lambda:get_data(username))
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))
                    await asyncio.sleep(30)
                except websockets.ConnectionClosed as e:
                    print(f'Terminated', e)
                    continue
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

WebSockets pack: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/

Send information ping min, max, avg every 30 seconds
And make sure that the client is connected as long as it is connected to the server

### **Django Consumer**

```
async def connect(self):
        try:
            self.username = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
            await database_sync_to_async(self.update_user_incr)(self.username)
        except KeyError as e:
            pass
          ......
async def disconnect(self, close_code):
     
        try:
            if(self.username):
                await database_sync_to_async(self.update_user_decr)(self.username)
        except:
            pass
        .......
```

The problem is that python script occasionally locks up with the message

`sent 1011 (unexpected error) keepalive ping timeout; no close frame received`

`no close frame received or sent`

and I can't call back automatic

**How can I keep the connection open or if it closes it reopens in a small percentage of time so that the front end cannot modify online or offline indicator**

Comment: This document may very helpful to understand this: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/common.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up reconnecting with something like this

```
 async for websocket in websockets.connect(url):
        try:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: get_data(username))
            await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed as e:
            print(f'Terminated', e)
```

But I had one problem which was adjusting the user state on every connection. In this case, you can use this [blog](http://www.djangocurrent.com/2011/07/django-using-cashing-to-track-online.html)  and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663777/how-to-check-whether-a-user-is-online-in-django-template) to lighten the load on the database

Comment: Any chance you figured out a better way to handle this? I'm running into the exact same issue where the a python websockets client closes every 40 seconds when connecting to a uwsgi websocket server.

Comment: actually, this way works well. In fact, this method is stopped after a while, but it is quickly reconnected, which is why I mentioned the use of caching